# Promises in several files

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm struggling to organise a series of operations in Javascript as Promises (as opposed to a async waterfall), with each promise in a file so that I can test it on its own.

Working main.js, but "p1.p1()" is ugly!

```
p1 = require("./test.js");

console.log(p1)

p1.p1().then(function(val) {
  console.log(val); // 1
  return val + 2;
}).then(function(val) {
  console.log(val); // 3
})
```

test.js, in future I would want to have several {1..X}.js to import:

```
exports.p1 = function() { return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { resolve(1); }); }
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this in Node 4.3?

Answer (score 1):

If your only problem with `p1.p1()` is the repetition of `p1` and you want to call it in a shorter manner, that in addition to your intention of having **only one** promise per file, then you can do as follows:

In `test.js`:

```
module.exports = function () {
    return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve(1)
    })
}
```

In `main.js`:

```
var p1 = require("./test.js")

p1()
    .then(function(p1_result) {
        console.log("Result of p1: ", p1_result)
    })
    .then(...)
    .catch(function(err) {
        // handle errors as you see fit in your case
    })
```

- Beware that attaching the function returning the promise in `test.js` to `module.exports` will mean that you can only export that one function, but you did explicitly state that that is what you want to do.

---

PS: If you don't **have** to use Node v4.3, you should consider using a more recent version (6.9.x LTS, or 7.4.x current)